# BrowserStrack integration with Panther for E2E Tests

Tags: symfony, browser, browserstack, e2e, symfony-panther

Does anyone has tried to integrate BrowserStack cloud solution into Panther ?

We use Panther (Chrome) for our E2E tests on our Github actions but most of our customers use Internet Explorer :( so we want to test with IE instead.

Panther does not allow to test with IE natively but When looking at the documentation (https://github.com/symfony/panther#readme) it does mention that Panther "support remote browser testing services including SauceLabs and BrowserStack" which would allow us to test with IE via BrowserStack.

However I can see nothing in the rest of the documentation that would explain how to integrate them together so I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Cheers!

PS: I don't know if it's important but we're using the PHP framework symfony v4.4